# upload picture from android to a php server

Tags: php, android, image

I'm trying to upload a `picture/imageview` to php server.
 This server for uploading photos looks like this:

```
<h2>Your Photo(s)
            <span style="font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a  href="javascript:toggleUpload('upload_pictures', 'upload_link')" id="upload_link">Add new photo!</a>
                            </span>
        </h2>
    <div id="upload_pictures" style="display: none;">

        <div id="leftcol"><form action="//here is set the homepage" 
                      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                      name="form" target="_self" id="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="a" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="100000894591455" />
```

The problem is that I don't know how to upload a picture properly on this server-desgined this way.
I don't know what codding method I should use or what to put in the post request.All my attempts of uploading a photo to that link returned a broken link!

If you would point me in the right direction I would really appreciate.Thanks

Comment: Hey george plz Follow this link [Liink][1] Hope helpfull for u....


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295417/upload-a-picture-from-android-to-php-server

Comment: I've been there but when I try to upload with this method it returns as an response a broken link!!!!Because the php server expects to get different format of the data and different coding method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http post request which send bytes of images along with appropriate headers and parameters can upload any file easily on a php server .
go through http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html

Comment: 've been there but when I try to upload with this method it returns as an response a broken link!!!!Because the php server expects to get different format of the data and different coding method!