# What is Server Side and how to set it up with Android application?

Tags: php, android

I'm developing an Android application that allow the user to upload and download PDF files from a public shared storage.
I don‘t want my app to ask the user for authorization as Dropbox does.
I found something called Server Side Client which receives upload requests from the app then deal with them.
Take a look at this topic: [Upload a picture from Android to PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295417/upload-a-picture-from-android-to-php-server?rq=1). 
My question is what is a server side and how to set it up. 
Actually I have no idea about it. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically interfacing a php application with a java class. So an event would be triggered on the mobile phone that would instantiate the class in turn utilizing the 'server side' script. You can easily find a php upload script and host it on a server which is referenced by your java class. But a good rule of thumb is to validate upload requests through a user session in the android application. You can store the authenticated user session in PHP $_SESSION variable and validate upload request from android phones. In addition users would only have access to files stored on the server they uploaded unless permission were granted to another user registered on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your time but what do you mean with "host it on a server"? Do you mean a site domain provider?

Comment: you can get php hosting on godaddy for 99cents. I mean a server with php support

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question but I have a very basic knowlage about these servers stuff. Is the server that you are talking about includes a website domain? Because I  do not feel comfortable if it does. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can access the server through an IP like http://28.382.238.32 but you can get a 99cent .info domain for very cheap. Do you have any valid concern for not wanting a domain?

Comment: No problem to me but what about the files that users uploads to the server. Where are thay going to be?

Comment: @Fahad they will be stored on the web server with access control security put in place