# How to recieve a Multipart request in PHP

Tags: php, android, api, multipart

We have API which receives images converted in base64 string. Our mobile application consumes too much RAM during the conversion process (to base64), now we need to upload image as multipart. I developed the mobile part but I'm stuck with the PHP API. We switched from volley to Retrofit because volley did not support multipart upload.

What do I need to change in the script that receives the multipart image upload?

```
<?php

//header('Content-Type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_POST["encoded_string"])) {

    //encoded_string -> base64 string sent from mobile phone

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name     = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'images/' . $image_name;

    if (!file_exists('images')) {
        mkdir('images', 0777, true);
    }

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if ($is_written > 0) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

        if ($connection) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO photos(name,path) values('$image_name','$path');";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            if ($result) {
                echo json_encode(array(
                   "response" => "Success! Image is succefully uploaded!.",     
                   "result" => "success"
                ));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "response" => "Error! Image is not uploaded.",
                    "result" => "error"
                ));
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "response" => "Error! No database connection!",
                "result" => "error"
            ));
        }
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        "response" => "Error! Please insert data!",
        "result" => "error"
    ));
}
?>
```

Comment: i have custom methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513174/android-multipart-image-upload-with-httpconnectionparams-deprecated-in-new-api/36513504#36513504) for upload pics it work by Json maybe help you.

Comment: Please remove the database code from your script. It has nothing to do with receiving an image. Concentrate on receiving. Keep the script small.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `move_uploaded_file()` function of php and the `$_FILES` array.

Example code plenty on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add multipart upload in backend you should make next changes:

```
<?php

//header('Content-Type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-Type: application/json');


if (isset($_POST["encoded_string"])) {


    //encoded_string -> base64 string sent from mobile phone
    if (!file_exists('images')) {
        mkdir('images', 0777, true);
    }

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

    if (!$connection) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "response" => "Error! No database connection!",
            "result" => "error"
        ));
        die;
    }

    $responses = array();

    foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $image_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
            $path = 'images/' . $image_name;
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, path)) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO photos(name,path) values('$image_name','$path');";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if ($result) {
                    $responses[] = array(
                        "response" => "Success! Image is succefully uploaded!.",
                        "result" => "success"
                    );
                } else {
                    $responses[] = array(
                        "response" => "Error! Image is not uploaded.",
                        "result" => "error"
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $responses[] = array(
                "response" => "Error! Please insert data!",
                "result" => "error"
            );
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
    echo json_encode(array(
        'responses' => $responses
    ));
}
```

Also, make shore you use post request with multipart format (it should have header Content-Type: multipart/form-data and bi in right format - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data). Hope it help you.